# Batch script to delete files/folder even open by user in share

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Can somebody guide me to delete folder/files in remote machine even when it's open by other user in share with write access.

I am getting error as

\remote\Destination\NEWFOL~2 - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I am using psfile command from sysinternals but the session is again created before deletion.. I can see the session is closed.. immediately after close another session is created

Comment: I told you this before: forcefully closing file handles is a BAD IDEA. Do NOT do this unless you have exhausted all other options. What is the actual problem you're so desparately trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I have to delete a folder which is in share.. but when someone with write access open that folder/file inside it .. it's not allowing me to delete... even I am using admin user for thet server.. but the requirement is we have to delete it irrespective of who open that session..

Comment: Is the folder itself shared? Or is it some (sub)folder inside a share? Does the server host other shares as well? And why would you need to repeatedly delete the folder?

Comment: yes the folder is in shared I have to delete all sub folder that were inside the share... this server host other share as well... I have to delete a folder since the requirement is have to clean up old file like monthly same folder and update with new one.. since some other user open the old file and forgot to close , I am not able to push new files...